# how to use for loop with bootstrap carousel

Tags: python, html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I have figured out how to use bootstrap carousel but problem is I want to render my featured stories to be in the carousel. 
currently I have a carousel that shows three slides, but what I'm trying to do is to have featured stories instead of the three slides.

```
 <div class='carousel slide' id="myCarousel">

      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li class="active" data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
        <li class="active" data-slide-to="1" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
        <li class="active" data-slide-to="2" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
      </ol>


      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active" id="slide1">
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/SQ691ZO.jpg" >
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h4>hello</h4>
            <p>hi you</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item" id="slide2">
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/zN4h51m.jpg" >

          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h4>hello</h4>
            <p>hi you</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item" id="slide3">
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/3ruWvoG.jpg">

          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h4>hello</h4>
            <p>hi you</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <a class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev" href="#myCarousel"><span class="icon-prev"></span></a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next" href="#myCarousel"><span class="icon-next"></span></a>
```

So this is what I tried that's not quite working. 
I have

```
    {% for a in featuredStory %}
    {{a.title}}
    {{a.sub}}
 <img src='{{a.get_featuredImage_url}}' class="img-rounded" alt="Cinque Terre" width="330" height="236"/>

    {% endfor %}
```

working fine, but problem is to incorporate these with carousel.
with one featured story it works but with more than one, I get one in the top one in the bottom.

Here;s what I tried

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    {% for a in featuredStory %}

    <div class='carousel slide' id="myCarousel">

      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li class="active" data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
        <li class="active" data-slide-to="1" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
        <li class="active" data-slide-to="2" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
      </ol>


      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active" id="slide1">
 <img src='{{a.get_featuredImage_url}}' class="img-rounded" alt="Cinque Terre" width="330" height="236"/>          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h4>    {{a.title}}</h4>
            <p>     {{a.sub}}
</p>
          </div>
        </div>




      </div>
      <a class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev" href="#myCarousel"><span class="icon-prev"></span></a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next" href="#myCarousel"><span class="icon-next"></span></a>

{% endfor %}

    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the for loop inside `carousel-inner`:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    {% for a in featuredStory %}
        <div class="item {% if forloop.counter == 1 %}active{% endif %}" id="slide{{ forloop.counter }}">
            <img src="{{ a.get_featuredImage_url }}" >
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h4>{{ a.title }}</h4>
                <p>{{ a.sub}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Make sure to activate the first item by checking the counter:

```
{% if forloop.counter == 1 %}active{% endif %}
```

If there are other information such as `class`, `title` etc. that also you can set in context on the `featuredStory` and then render it here same as `title` or `url`.

Answer (score 1):

Create `div[class=item]`   dynamically with `for loop` in next way:

```
{% for item in featuredStory %}
<div class="item" id="slide{{forloop.counter}}">
    <img src="item.get_featuredImage_url">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
     <h4>{{ item.title }}</h4>
     <p>{{ item.sub }}</p>
   </div>
 </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used loop.index instead of forloop.counter

```
 <div class="carousel-inner">
        {% for item in sliders %}
          <div class="carousel-item {% if loop.index == 1 %}active{% endif %}" id="slide{{ loop.index }}" >
            <img class="d-block w-100"  width="330" height="236" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/sliders/') }}{{ item.imagelocation }}" alt="{{item.filmtitle}}">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h4>{{ item.filmtitle }}</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
```